# Method from ball class not working in the main(Game1) class but no error

Tags: c#, monogame, pong

This method in the ball class should reset the ball position:

```
public void ResetBall()
{
    _drawRect.X = GameConstants.WINDOWWIDTH / 2 - _halfDrawRectangleWidth;
    _drawRect.Y = GameConstants.WINDOWHEIGHT / 2 - _halfDrawRectangleHeight;
}
```

I use constants from the GameConstants class:

```
static class GameConstants
{
    public const int WINDOWHEIGHT = 800;
    public const int WINDOWWIDTH = 1200;
}
```

I tried using ResetBall()in the main class called Game1 in the Update method using:

```
_ball.ResetBall();
_ball.Update(gameTime);
```

I get no compile errors at all I make the object I update it I draw it and everything worked what you need for a pong game just the ball reset doesn't work the method from the ball class is Public maybe it has something to do with the rectangle I made IN the ball class

```
_drawRect = new Rectangle((int)_location.X - _halfDrawRectangleWidth, 
      (int)_location.Y - _halfDrawRectangleHeight, _spriteBall.Width, _spriteBall.Height);
```

I actually just tried to reset the drawrectangle X and Y positions

Comment: What is the definition of `not working`?

Comment: I use it in my main update, but it doesn't do anything, it doesn't affect the ball position, in other words my ball doesn't reset but I don't get any errors. If I use it in my ball class itself in the update it works as intended.

Comment: I think I found the problem it's because _ball.Update(gameTime); was after the _ball.ResetBall(); instead of before